How to Dispatch Redux Actions from WebSocket onMessage in Redux-Saga?
I am developing a React Native app using Redux and Redux-Saga for state management and handling side effects. I’ve implemented WebSocket communication for a chat feature. Everything works fine. But,Here's the issue:
I want to dispatch the RECEIVE_MESSAGE action when the WebSocket receives a new message > (onMessage).
I tried using the put effect, but it doesn’t work directly inside the WebSocket callback since it operates outside the Saga context and not work as expected.
saga.js ->
import { takeEvery, put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import webSocketService from '../../utils/WebSocketService';

import { SEND_MESSAGE, RECEIVE_MESSAGE, CONNECT, DISCONNECT } from '../constant';
// Action types

// Saga: Connect to WebSocket
function* connectWebSocketSaga(action) {
  try {
    const { receiverId } = action.payload;
    yield call([webSocketService, webSocketService.connect], receiverId);


    // Listen for incoming messages
    webSocketService.onMessage((message) => {
      console.log("Message from server:", message);
      // Dispatch the message to Redux store
      put({ type: RECEIVE_MESSAGE, payload: message });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting WebSocket:', error);
  }
}

// Saga: Disconnect WebSocket
function* disconnectWebSocketSaga() {
  try {
    yield call([webSocketService, webSocketService.disconnect]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error disconnecting WebSocket:', error);
  }
}

// Saga: Send Message
function* sendMessageSaga(action) {
  try {
    const { message } = action.payload;
    if (message) {
      console.log('send saga ->', { message });
      yield call([webSocketService, webSocketService.send], message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending WebSocket message:', error);
  }
}

// Root Saga
export default function* chatSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(CONNECT, connectWebSocketSaga);
  yield takeEvery(DISCONNECT, disconnectWebSocketSaga);
  yield takeEvery(SEND_MESSAGE, sendMessageSaga);
}


WebSocketService.js
class WebSocketService {
    static instance = null;
  
    constructor() {
      if (!WebSocketService.instance) {
        WebSocketService.instance = this;
        this.socket = null;
      }
      return WebSocketService.instance;
    }
  
    connect(receiverId) {
      const url = `ws://192.168.xxxx.yyyy:8000/ws/chat/${receiverId}/`;
      this.socket = new WebSocket(url);
  
      this.socket.onopen = () => console.log('WebSocket connected to:', url);
      
      this.socket.onclose = (event) => {
        console.log(`WebSocket closed with code ${event.code}`);
      };
      this.socket.onerror = (error) => console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
    }
  
    send(data) {
      if (this.socket && this.socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
      } else {
        console.error('WebSocket is not connected');
      }
    }
  
    onMessage(callback) {
      if (this.socket) {
        this.socket.onmessage = (event) => {
          const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
          callback(data);
        };
      }
    }
  
    disconnect() {
      if (this.socket) {
        this.socket.close();
        this.socket = null;
      }
    }
  }
  
  const webSocketService = new WebSocketService();
  export default webSocketService;

I have tried chatGPT for the issues its answer is not satisfactorily. Its one of the response uses eventChannel that seems to work correctly. but i afraid of the line while (true) that keeps listening infinetly for the new message and i think this can reduce my app performance in production or in local development.
function* connectWebSocketSaga(action) {
  try {
    const { receiverId } = action.payload;
    yield call([webSocketService, webSocketService.connect], receiverId);

    // Create a channel to listen for WebSocket messages
    const socketChannel = yield call(createWebSocketChannel, webSocketService.socket);

    // Listen for incoming messages
    while (true) {
      const message = yield take(socketChannel);
      yield put({ type: RECEIVE_MESSAGE, payload: message }); // Dispatch message to Redux
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("WebSocket connection failed:", error);
  }
}

Could someone guide me on the best way to dispatch Redux actions for incoming WebSocket messages in Redux-Saga? Any code examples or explanations would be greatly appreciated!
